# ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, I got two scene 'Opening' 'Main'.

If there's no keydown in put for a while or complete the task,
It will go back to Opening scene and can start again.

It works, to go Opening scene -> Main scene
and go to the Main scene -> Opening scene

However 'Main scene -> Opening scene' and when I try to go Main scene again,
It shows these error. :

```
ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[KeyDelayData+Delay,UnityEngine.Sprite]].Add (Int32 key, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 value) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:404)
Note.Init () (at Assets/Scripts/Music/Note.cs:22)
ManagerChat.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Chatting/ManagerChat.cs:315)

ArgumentException: An element with the same key already exists in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,UnityEngine.AudioClip].Add (Int32 key, UnityEngine.AudioClip value) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:404)
SoundManager.Awake () (at Assets/Scripts/Music/SoundManager.cs:16)
```

It looks like some resetting variable issue for me but I don't know what it mean
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you using `Dictionary`? If not, then a plugin you are using is using a Dictionary while trying to add an existing key again.

Comment: yes I'm using Dictionary on several script.

Comment: I fix second one by using DictionaryValue.Clear ();  but I still can't fix first one

Comment: I fix the first one by simply Clear the Value like the second one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an existing key to a `Dictionary`.

The first error in the `Awake` function from the `ManagerChat` script on line *315*.

The second error in the `Awake` function from the `SoundManager` script on line *16*.

Solution:

**1**.[`Dictionary.Clear()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963777/3785314) should do it but if you don't want to clear them then check if the key is already in the `Dictionary` before adding it with the `Dictionary.Add` function:

Let's say this is your code:

```
Dictionary<int, Sprite> imageDict = new Dictionary<int, Sprite>();
int keyToAdd = 1;
imageDict.Add(keyToAdd, new Sprite());
```

Change it to:

```
Dictionary<int, Sprite> imageDict = new Dictionary<int, Sprite>();
int keyToAdd = 1;
//Add only if key does not exist
if (!imageDict.ContainsKey(keyToAdd))
{
    imageDict.Add(keyToAdd, new Sprite());
}
```

---

**2**.Another way to do this is to use the index(`[]`) as key to change it. This does **not** involve the `Dictionary.Add` function.

```
Dictionary<int, Sprite> imageDict = new Dictionary<int, Sprite>();
int keyToAdd = 1;
imageDict.Add(keyToAdd, new Sprite());
```

Should be:

```
Dictionary<int, Sprite> imageDict = new Dictionary<int, Sprite>();
int keyToAdd = 1;
imageDict[keyToAdd] = new Sprite();
```

Comment: Thanks for your much smater way to approach! It is much better!

Answer (score 0):

I fix both by using DictionaryValue.Clear ();

It was about the remain object and sprites I think.

Comment: Kind of shortcut for me but It works too on my project!

Comment: That should work. It depends on if you want to clear the dictionary or not. You are welcome!